# Error in Angular aot build: Expression form not supported

Tags: angular, angular-aot

I get some errors when building in order to enable Server Side Rendering. Here I get the errors:

```
const lang = ( typeof localStorage!=='undefined' && localStorage.getItem("lang") ) ? localStorage.getItem("lang") : config.defaultLang;
```

Errors:

```
ERROR in src\app\app-routing.module.ts(6,16): Error during template compile of 'AppRoutingModule'
Expression form not supported.
```

Answer (score 4):

this is mostly due to dobule comma in routes,atleast in my cases, make sure you dont have ,, in AppRoutingModule, remove one, recompile

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I don't think this relates to my case.